# How to change the default license selection in `civix generate:module`?

Tags: civix

By default `civix generate:module` will create an extension licensed with AGPL-3.0. How would one go about changing that default to something else, say, GPL-3.0?

**Edit:** I'm aware of the --license argument, but to clarify, I'm looking to change the default license permanently, so that I would have e.g. GPL-3.0 on all future invocations of `civix generate:module`, without additional arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use any of the licenses in https://github.com/totten/license-data/blob/master/index.csv, which is used by civix.

In your case, just add `--license=GPL-3.0` to the command.

It looks like you may be able to set a value in `~/.civix/civix.ini` to provide a local default: https://github.com/totten/civix/blob/v16.03.2/src/CRM/CivixBundle/Command/InitCommand.php#L118

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I should have been more specific, in that I'm looking to change the default setting permanently, not just override it on a per-use basis. I've edited the question.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding--added something that should help.

Comment: OK, I had to upgrade civix, but that was easy enough. Thanks!